# How to make a css background image move in x and y direction?

Tags: html, css, background, transition

What I want is a repeated background image , boxes for example , that moves in direction x and y repeated animation too.

Comment: I mean the background scroll horizontally and vertically.

Comment: I'm sort of confused by what you are asking but by default backgrounds repeat in both the X & Y axis

Answer (score 0):

make a gif image and set it as background or you can use javascript setInterval function or jquery animate function to change background image.

Comment: What I want is png or jpg scrolling vertically and horizontally

Comment: use a div element and add your background  images in html and set their position absolute and use z-index property to make those images in background and then use javascript setInterval function or jquery animate function for your desired animation.